# prove that an equation is bounded by 1

Tags: inequality, logarithms, proof-explanation

I have an equation that is bounded by 1 and where $s<m$, how can I prove it that it actually bounded by 1.
The equation is:

$\frac{-m}{s}(1-\frac{s}{m})\ln(1-\frac{s}{m})$

Any help will be useful to me.

thanks

Comment: This expression has one specific bound that is provided by the $\ln$ function together with the assumption that the result must be a real number.  Is this assumption correct?  Also, hint: can this expression be rearranged in part or as a whole to look like a limit definition for the number $e$?

Comment: well actually this equation is an exponent of the term e. that is the only limitation

Comment: and your assumption is correct

Comment: What are $s$ and $m$? Are you trying to prove that 1 is an *upper* bound?

Comment: it is the upper bound and $s$ and $m$ are some positive quantity

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{s}{m}$. So $0<x<1$, we want to prove that $-\frac{1}{x}(1-x)\ln(1-x)\leq 1$.

$$-\frac{1}{x}(1-x)\ln(1-x)-1 = (1-\frac{1}{x})\ln(1-x)-1=\frac{(x-1)\ln(1-x)-1}{x}$$

$x>0$ so it is enough to prove that $(x-1)\ln(1-x)\leq 1$ or $\ln(1-x)\geq \frac{1}{x-1}$ we changed sign because $x-1<0$.

Let $f(t)=\ln(1-t)-\frac{1}{t-1}$ than $f'(t)= \frac{-1}{1-t}+\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}=\frac{t-1+1}{(t-1)^2}\geq0$ for $t\geq 0$. $f(0)=0$, so $f(t)\geq0$ and we are done.